# What token can I use for the taxonomy hierarchy?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, tokens

I have a vocabulary with 3 levels and a content type with a term reference to that vocabulary.
When I create a node of that type, I choose a term in the deepest level of the vocabulary. I installed the Pathauto module and I'd like to use *[node:field_category:level-1]/[node:field_category:level-2]/[node:field_category:level-3(deepest)]/[node:title]* as pattern.

The problem is that I can't find the right token to achieve this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[node:field-yourfield:parents:join:/]/[node:title]* works for me, where *yourfield* is the name of your reference field.

You have to go to *Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases Settings*; under *Punctuation* change *Slash* to *Do nothing*, to avoid slashes are removed from the path alias.